# S3 bucket - limit number of downloads for a specific IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to put some files on S3 bucket for a customer to download.
However, I want to restrict the number of download for the IAM user.

Is there any way to achieve this without deploying any additional service?

I have come across metrics to track how many times the customer has downloaded a file, but I havent found a way to restrict it to a specific number.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to do this directly, after checking [Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) do not provide a way to control the number of GET operations.

What you can do is to Create an Alarm for the metric you came across that will trigger a Lambda function to add a Deny policy to the IAM user on the specified files when the threshold is reached.

Comment: Wouldnt that need an alarm for each file?

Comment: An alternative would be creating a trail in Cloudtrail for Read operations. then configure Cloudtrail to trigger your Lambda as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail.html.  Last thing would be to store the number of READ operations in for DynamoDB and check every time the Lambda gets invoked the number of reads and whenever the user hits the limit you add the deny policy.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible to limit the number of downloads** of objects from Amazon S3. You would need to write your own application that authenticates users and then serves the content *via the application*.

An alternative is to provide a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that is valid for only a short period of time, with the expectation that this would not provide enough time for multiple downloads.